# How to set background color based on hover effect i.e when mouse over on li item in same css definition defined for background-color for class?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply `background-color` to `<li>` on hover, but the hover effect is not working with the CSS I had defined in the same declaration block used to set the background color of the item. How can I use comma-separated CSS for the hover effect without creating another CSS rule?

```css
.main-menu .acc .fa-home,
.main-menu li:hover>fa-home {
  background-color: #689f38;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="acc">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          Manage Account
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was with `...li:hover>fa-home { ...` here you are targeting tag element ***fa-home***, which you don't have (you have only class by that name) and also using rule **>** which stands that your tag element is directly after **li** tag, but you have ***a*** tag

```css
.main-menu .acc .fa-home,
.main-menu li:hover {
    background-color:#689f38;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
       <li class="acc">
           <a href="#">
               <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
               <span class="nav-text">
                   Manage Account
               </span>
           </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

if you on hover want to change background color of element with class .fa-home, then you should do something like this:

```
..., .main-menu li:hover .fa-home {
  background-color: red;
}
```